# Killing a Node.js program from a shell script

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I'm running a node.js application which is acting as a man-in-the-middle proxy to proxy all of the requests I'm making through a PhantomJS headless testing environment. I want to spin up this proxy from either my PhantomJS test script (though I've looked into it and it seems that phantom does not have an `exec()` command for executing shell commands) or a small shell script which manages both processes. Ideally, it would do something like

```
#!/bin/bash
node proxy.js
phantomjs runTests.js
kill node process here
```

Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moments after asking this question, I found a much better way to execute the phantom program from within my node app by using a child process. I placed my phantom script within the folder which contained my node app, and then used exec like this:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var _phantom = exec('phantomjs runTests.js',function(error,stdout,stderr){
    console.log(stdout);
};

_phantom.on('exit',function(code,sig){
    process.exit(code);
});
```

This means I could spin up my proxy server, then execute the child process. The `_phantom.on('exit')` block allows me to detect when the process exits on a code. Then, it's very simple to signal the node app to quit, using `process.exit`.